# HTML5 download attribute detect download start

Tags: download, prompt

Using html5 download attribute, is it possible to detect when the file has actually been downloaded? Some browsers offer prompt box, and the user can click cancel instead, while other browsers automatically start download by clicking on the link.

```
 <a href="path/to/file" download >download here</a>
```

I need to count number of downloads, if its not possible this way, is there other option?

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to do this is not possible. You don't want to count with the client side, rather the server side. The way you could do this is whenever the server finishes a download, you could add one to your counter. An easy (but there are better ways) of doing this would be to create something like a `downloadhandler.php` where it would tally a download every time you loaded it, and echo something like: 
`<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=your-download-url"></head></html>`, to redirect you to the download URL.

Comment: 1. What is the main reason for not doing this client side?    2. What if you wanted to track 'likes', would you use similar method?

Comment: People can mess with your client side code. You can change it all you want, even on stack overflow, but this is reliable, because for every time it's downloaded, it will be counted, no matter what. If you wanted to track likes, you'd do something like make a `likehandler.php` where it would track how many likes there are in an internal file. The client side would be making a request to the like handler, and server side you'd keep a file to track how many likes you want.

Comment: These solution are complicated and involve htaccess to prevent browser playing the file and what not. Isnt there a way to merge html5 download attribute and making it server side count?

Comment: For one, no, it doesn't but anyway, I'll make a function for you that can count it. Tell me, are you using PHP?